# Copy a file's text to another file PHP

Tags: php

I want to copy the content from (Bazamod.txt) to (compile.txt) but I get this error:

> Warning: fopen(LicenteSi/Test/compile.txt): failed to open stream: No
> such file or directory in
> /storage/ssd3/361/16261361/public_html/createL.php on line 137
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
> /storage/ssd3/361/16261361/public_html/createL.php on line 141

```
Function create_compile_mod($Licence_Name, $Path){
      $FilePath = "$Path/compile.txt";
        $myFile = fopen($FilePath, "r+");
        
            copy("bazamod/Bazamod.txt", $FilePath);
        
        fwrite($myFile, $FilePath);
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: use `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` functions

Comment: how are you calling the function? Can you add that to the question and possibly explain/show the directory structure?

Comment: bluepinto helped, I managed to finish it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Using the combination of `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` means that you read all content into memory. Fine for trivial content, though it is obviously much slower than an internal file system operation. But this won't scale. Instead you should try to understand _why_ your `copy` approach did not work. And fix that. This most likely is a path issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you what you need to do is just to copy the contents of `Bazamod.txt` to `compile.txt`, by providing a path to `compile.txt` as argument, then the following function will do the trick:

```
<?php
function create_compile_mod($Path)
{
    $fileContents = file_get_contents("bazamod/Bazamod.txt");
    $fileHandle = fopen($Path . "/compile.txt", "r+");
    fputs($fileHandle, $fileContents);
    fclose($fileHandle);
}
?>
```

I have not included your `$Licence_Name` argument as it does not seem to be used, but you can adapt the above code to fit your needs.

Keep in mind that the above code will copy the entire contents of `Bazamod.txt` and replace the existing contents of `compile.txt`. If you would just like to append new text, use the `"a"` access mode instead of the specified `"r+"`, and the text will automatically be added at the bottom of the document.

If you need to add at a specific line, you could go for:

```
<?php
function create_compile_mod($Path, $lineIndex)
{
    $oldContents = file_get_contents("bazamod/Bazamod.txt");
    $compileArray = file($Path . "compile.txt");

    array_splice($compileArray, $lineIndex, 0, $oldContents); 
    $newContent = implode(PHP_EOL, $compileArray);

    $compileFh = fopen($Path . "compile.txt", "r+");
    fputs($compileFh, $newContent);
}
?>
```

Specify your `$lineIndex` to be the line number at which you want you content to be put (starting from line 0), and call your function like `create_compile_mod("./", 4)`.